# sublime text : open containing folder

Tags: editor, sublimetext2, text-editor, sublimetext

I'm working on some file in my sublime text 2 editor, and I want to open a folder in which that file resides.

I know there is a 2 step procedure to do this already

```
step 1: right click and reveal in sidebar (ctrl+shift+r)
step 2: right click on the same file in sidebar and click open containing folder.
```

I would like to know if there is only one shortcut key to do the same. This is something that I use quite often.

Comment: Although you cannot right click on the tab for a file to get the "Open containing..." option, you can right click on the editor area of a file to directly open it.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

You can add the line below to your `Default (Windows).sublime-keymap`:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+e"], "command": "open_dir", 
    "args": {"dir": "$file_path", "file": "$file_name"} }
```

Comment: You can copy and paste above inside [] after you click on Preferences > "Key Bindings - User" menu.

Comment: Strange. Maybe this key combination is overwritten globally by another app.
 On my mac I'm using: `super+shift+e`

Comment: AFAIK, there isn't one. You'd need a plugin for that.

Comment: I did as said, It's not working! I am using sublime text 3 on windows. Rechecking...Ok, got it, It worked. I missed a comma. LOL. Programmers biggest nightmare. Felt escaped! :D

Comment: Remapping to a different key combination worked for me, as [tborychowski suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19410938/sublime-text-open-containing-folder#comment74818651_19561427).

Answer (score 13):

By default the editor has this item in context menu. If you need this feature on tabs you have to create a file with name "Tab Context.sublime-menu" in "\Data\Packages\User\" (if does not exist yet) and add this code:

```
[
    {
        "caption": "-"
    },
    {
        "command": "open_dir",
        "args": {"dir": "$file_path", "file": "$file_name"},
        "caption": "Open Containing Folder…"
    }
]
```

Do not forget formatting lines as a JSON file! If you do not need a separator before this menu item you need to delete first block with caption "-"! You can add any other menu in this file. For example:

```
{
    "command": "copy_path",
    "caption": "Copy File Path"
},
```

Comment: `By default the editor has this item in context menu.`
The latest Sublime versions seem to have lost this ability somehow, I can no longer right click on the file name at the top.

Comment: This worked for me!
I was able to open the directory By
Topbar Menu -> Preferences -> Browse Packages (add `User\MyNewPlugin` folder here, and add the `Tab Context.sublime-menu` file inside that folder, w/ the specified contents)

Answer (score 3):

Install [Open project path by shortcut](https://github.com/Shagabutdinov/sublime-open-path).  Then setup keybindings in your User keymap file

```
{
  "keys": ["f10"],
  "command": "open_project_folder"
},

{
  "keys": ["ctrl+f10"],
  "command": "open_file_folder"
}
```

Initiate the key bindings on a open file (f10 to open the directory you have set as the project folder, ctrl+f10 to open the folder of the current file.)

Comment: isn't there any inbuilt key for this? Do I have to install a new package?

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me: assuming you have opened the file whose enclosing folder you want to open, use the `Menu > Project > Add Folder To Project` command.

A new window should open with the enclosing folder. Just click 'Open' and you're done!

Answer (score 2):

I found this plugin: https://github.com/kallepersson/Sublime-Finder

The instructions are pretty straightforward-- I just use `CMD+SHIFT+P` and type "finder" and press enter and it opens a finder window.

I think this might only work on macs though.

Answer (score 1):

In sublimetext3 there is a package to sync current open file with the sidebar explorer.
**SyncedSidebar**