# Sublime text: open containing folder with power shell

Tags: powershell, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I've found how to [open a folder in explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19410938/1075247) from sublime text 2, how can I open the folder with an arbitrary program, like Powershell?

I'm not looking for Powershell commands, I'm looking for keyboard shortcuts/functions etc to open a fold in a sublime text instance in powershell.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to open an explorer window from powershell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320509/is-it-possible-to-open-an-explorer-window-from-powershell)

Comment: @Kev Wrong way round. I don't want to open Sublime from Powershell, I want to open Powershell **from** sublime. Is my edit any clearer?

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for posting this question, I learned something new today as well when answering it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this type of thing you're now into the realm of having to write your own Sublime Text plugin which involves dabbling in some Python.

In a nutshell, you'd decide on which key mappings you want to use to open a PowerShell window (and ideally it'd open that window with PowerShell set to use the path of where your currently edited file resides), for example:

```
{
  "keys": ["shift+f12"],
  "command": "open_powershell_window"
}
```

You'd then map this to the desired behaviour (open a PowerShell window) in your plugin:

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin
# maps to open_powershell_window by converting to lower case and word-
# splitting using underscores
class OpenPowerShellWindowCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        # magic to open and run powershell
```

However, fortunately there's a plugin called [Sublime Terminal](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/terminal) which does this for us (and for other shells, depending on your OS). It'll either open a terminal window with the path set to your project folder, or your currently edited file.

You can install this using [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/), just do `Install Package` and search for "*Terminal*" (look for the wbond.net url in the description to make sure you get the right one, it's at v1.4.0 just now).

You can find the source code here:

> https://github.com/wbond/sublime_terminal